# Github action manual execution not working

Tags: github-actions, building-github-actions

I have 3 different workflows in a project configured at top as:

plan_streamline.yml

```
name: plan

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

...
```

terrform_import.yml

```
name: terraform_import

on: workflow_dispatch
...
```

plan.yml

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
```

But within the github action I do not see the ability to manually execute any of the workflows, as I should be seeing something like https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-06-github-actions-manual-triggers-with-workflow_dispatch/

What is wrong with my workflow configuration?

Comment: You can't filter the `workflow_dispatch` event by branch, but simply having it there as a trigger should make the button in the actions tab show up.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Updated my question, it still does not work...

Comment: Is the workflow with that trigger merged into the default branch?

Comment: @BenjaminW. every workflow has the trigger so yes every branch has this

Comment: If your repo is public, can you link to it?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I did not merge the branch with the new workflows to the default branch so that option did not appear...it's fine now

Comment: I wonder if there might be a syntax / validation error for the YAML? That was my problem.  Maybe try this? https://github.com/mpalmer/action-validator

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Merged the branch with the new workflows to the default branch so that option appears now

Answer (score 0):

According to the information [on this page](https://build5nines.com/configuring-manual-triggers-in-github-actions-with-workflow_dispatch/), in the section *"Configure branches"*, the following:

```
name: Manual Trigger Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches:
      - main
```

should work for any branch specified.